# Creating All Day Event failing

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, spfx

I'm trying to create an All Day event:

```
let foobar: any = {
    "subject": calendarEvent.Title+"v5",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "HTML",
        "content": calendarEvent! || !calendarEvent.Description ? "No Description": calendarEvent.Description,
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": calendarEvent.EventDate,
        "timeZone": moment.tz.guess(),
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": calendarEvent.EndDate,
        "timeZone": moment.tz.guess(),
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": !calendarEvent || !calendarEvent.Location ? "No Location": calendarEvent.Location,
    },
    "isAllDay": !calendarEvent || !calendarEvent.fAllDayEvent ? false : true,
};

context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient()
    .then((client: MSGraphClient) => {
        client.api("/me/calendar/events").post(foobar)
        .then((content: any) => {
            console.log("CalendarService | createCalendarEvent | content: ", content);
        });
    });
```

**Log:**

[image]

When I include the `isAllDay" property, it fails with a 400 (Bad Request).

I exclude the property, and it's creating the event w/out issue.

Any suggestions?

---

**EDIT:**  forgot to mention, if I pass `isAllDay` as `false`, the event is created.

**EDIT2:** This is connecting through the MSGraphClient from an SPFx project.

Comment: What API are you accessing?

Comment: @cmaynard MSGraph

Comment: Could it be that your start and end times aren't midnight:
https://www.eliostruyf.com/creating-all-day-events-with-the-microsoft-graph-on-office-365/

Comment: @cmaynard that did, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating an "All Day" event, you `start` and `end` times should only specify the *date*, not the date and time (or more accurately, the time should be 00:00:00):

```
let foobar: any = {
    "subject": calendarEvent.Title+"v5",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "HTML",
        "content": calendarEvent! || !calendarEvent.Description ? "No Description": calendarEvent.Description,
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": !calendarEvent.fAllDayEvent ? calendarEvent.EventDate : calendarEvent.EventDate.setTime(0),
        "timeZone": moment.tz.guess(),
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": !calendarEvent.fAllDayEvent ? calendarEvent.EventDate : calendarEvent.EventDate.setTime(0),
        "timeZone": moment.tz.guess(),
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": !calendarEvent || !calendarEvent.Location ? "No Location": calendarEvent.Location,
    },
    "isAllDay": !calendarEvent || !calendarEvent.fAllDayEvent ? false : true,
};

context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient()
    .then((client: MSGraphClient) => {
        client.api("/me/calendar/events").post(foobar)
        .then((content: any) => {
            console.log("CalendarService | createCalendarEvent | content: ", content);
        });
    });
```

Comment: That was in fact the issue, as I pointed out in the comments, thanks for providing a code sample.